# Не получается отодвинуть вправо "Telegram Vk Instagram". margin-left не работает!

Tags: html, css

[image]

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Магазин</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prompt:ital,wght@0,400;1,300&family=Teko:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header class="header" id="header">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="nav">
              <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" width="100" height="100">
              <div class="words"> Кондитерские изделия на заказ 
              </div>
              <div class="call">
                <a href="АДРЕС СТРАНИЦЫ" style="text-decoration: none; color:black;">Telegram</a>
                <a href="АДРЕС СТРАНИЦЫ" style="text-decoration: none; color:black;">Vk</a>
                <a href="АДРЕС СТРАНИЦЫ" style="text-decoration: none; color:black;">Instagram</a>       
              </div>
              <a href="#" class="menu">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
          </a>        
        </div>
      </div>
   </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #411F1F;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif ;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.header {
    background: #FFE4E4;
}

.container{
   margin-left:92px;
   margin-right: 92px;

}

.nav{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center ;
 
}

.words{
   font-size: 15px;
}

}
.call{
    font-size: 30px;
    word-spacing:30px;
    margin-left: 700px;
}

.menu{
    justify-content: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    width: 34px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left:auto;
    
}

.menu span{
    background: #411F1F;
    display: block;
    width: 34px;
    height: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.menu span:nth-child(2){
    width: 29px;
}
.menu span:nth-child(3){
    width: 21px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас просто не валидный css, уберите лишнюю } перед классом .call